# validation in struts 2 using xml file

Tags: validation, struts2

```
    <field-validator type="requiredstring">

        <message>password  required,enter again</message>

    </field-validator>


   <field-validator type="fieldexpression">
    <param name="expression">password.equals('prernagolani')</param>
        <message>invalid password</message>
    </field-validator>

</field>
```

this is the xml file for validation of my password field,but when i submit form with empty string it is showing both the errors

1.invalid password
2.password  required,enter again

i want if feild is empty then it should show only second message not the first one mentioned above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User Short-circuiting validators: http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/validation.html#Validation-ShortCircuitingValidator

*"A FieldValidator that gets short-circuited will only prevent other FieldValidators for the same field from being evaluated."*